# Is it possible to stream nested Json list?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

The API responds with the following `"application/json"` body type construct:

```
{
  "transactions": [
    {
      "transaction": "1",
    },
    {
      "transaction": "2",
    },
        {
      "transaction": "3",
    }
  ]
```

}

essentially I mapped it to..

```
    public class Transactions {
     private List<Transaction> transactions;
       ...
    }
```

Currently I retrieve it as a `Mono<Transactions>`, but it has drawbacks - it buffers whole list in memory.

With `Spring Reactive API`, is it possible to process list of transactions as Flux in a way that it does not get buffered in memory as a whole?

Many thanks!

Comment: where are you fetching the list from, if the list is fetched as a whole, then there is no meaning to just convert it to flux and push it out.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf it is an api call, with response type application/json... I think it is fetched as a whole. Does the api itself need to send it in a different way? Am i basically constrained by it?

Comment: if you do a call to a rest api that is blocking, your application will initiate the call, and wait for the response. When the response comes it will receive the entire list. Then there is no reason to push each item one by one when you already have the entire list. If the api you are calling is not reactive, then you will always get the entire list in one go.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf thanks, if you post it as an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After receiving more information in the comments this is the answer to the question.

If a webflux application is making a blocking call to a non-webflux api, measures should be made to wrap the call in a `Mono#fromCallable` and placed on it's own thread so that it does not interfere with the rest of the non blocking threads. All this is documented in the reactor documentation under their [faq](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking)

A blocking call will always return a single response, a `Mono` so in the above case it will return a `List<Transaction>`.

Since we already have the full list after the blocking call, most of the time there is no actual purpose to put this in a flux and then push these one by one out to the client.

So returning a `Mono<List<Transaction>>` to the calling client is probably the way to go.